# Can I Upload My html css files into netlify

Tags: netlify

Its not a problem .Iam asking about netlify .

I want to upload my responsive website into netlify

Help me to uplaod the html files into netlify  expecting more clear answers from you and i need to learn about how the netlify is working for the website of static and dynamic